# using iframe: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest'

Tags: javascript, django, iframe, xmlhttprequest

I'm using Django 1.6 and Apache for my website, at the beginning my web site worked fine, but when I put it in a iframe, it appeared this in the console:

> Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://www.example.com'

My iframe looks like this, which is simple:

```
    <iframe src="http://www.example.com" width="700" 
      height="400" sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts" style="border: 1px></iframe>
```

And the javascript part who occured this error is :

```
getData: function (url, params, method, cb, async) {
    if (async == "undefined") var async = true;
    if (params)  var par = JSON.stringify(params);
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   
      if (xmlhttp.overrideMimeType) {
          xmlhttp.overrideMimeType("text/xml");
        }
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
          xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch(e) {
            try {
                xmlhttp = new ActivetXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch(e2) {}
        }
    }
    if (!xmlhttp) {
        return cb();
    }
    xmlhttp.open(method, url, async);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    /**
     * Description
     * @method onreadystatechange
     * @return 
     */
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        cb(xmlhttp.responseText);
      }
    }
    if (params)  xmlhttp.send(par);
    else     xmlhttp.send();
  },
```

I've already set `X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'ALLOWALL'` in `settings.py` and have run the command `chromium-browser --disable-web-security` but still not working. However in the browser console Network part, the status of `XHR` request is `200`. I've google for a long time but didn't find the solution, hope you would have some advice. Thanks.

PS: Here is my Network console:

```
Response Headers
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Tue, 14 Jun 2016 14:00:45 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.6
X-Frame-Options: ALLOWALL
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

Comment: What does network tab of the console say about the request?? Seems like a CORS issue.

Comment: The status of the XHR request is 200, so I wonder if it is the problem of recevicem, any idea please?